# The need for Maya

Tags: krishna, dharma, maya

Why is there a need for Maya? Lord Krishna can run a world full of happiness without any Maya and sorrow? That would keep everyone happy. Wouldn't it? What is the justification given by Krishna for having Maya and sorrow in this World? Why can't he make everyone do Bhakti? He is all powerful enough to do it?

Comment: This is a good answer: https://www.quora.com/Why-did-Lord-Krishna-create-Maya/answer/Satya-Tathya Since we will live an eternal life, there is no need anymore. It will exist only inside movies/series though ;)

Comment: The answer was good @m4n0....Thank you